# Running a Tomcat Server from within a Java Class - ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, tomcat, automation, processbuilder

I have come across a problem when trying to run a process with Java.. Specifically trying to run a tomcat server from within my Java application. I have spent hours researching all of the posts available both on stackoverflow and google, tried the different solutions and nothing works for me. Essentially, I am building a automated testing tool which allows tests to be run on different sites. I have treid both Process and ProcessBuilder to execute this task for me. There are three methods used to try and invoke the tomcat server which are shown below:

```
public void convertCouncilNameToExecutableProcess(String councilName) {

    System.out.println("In convert method");
    if (councilName.equalsIgnoreCase("Manchester")) {
        councilRunner = "claims_manchestertest";
        runCouncilProcess(councilRunner);
    } else if (councilName.equalsIgnoreCase("Coventry")) {
        councilRunner = "claims_coventrytest";
        runCouncilProcess(councilRunner);
    }

}


private void runCouncilProcess(String councilName) {

    try {
        List<String> commandList = buildCommandList(councilName);
        ProcessBuilder buildProcess = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
        buildProcess.start();
        String output = IOUtils.toString(buildProcess.start().getInputStream());
        System.out.println("In process method " + output);
        System.out.println("Council: " + councilName + " is running successfully..");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private List<String> buildCommandList(String councilName) {
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("sudo");
    command.add("/opt");
    command.add("/" + councilName);
    command.add("/tomcat");
    command.add("/bin");
    command.add("/becs_tomcat");
    command.add(" console");
    return command;

}
```

As we have multiple councils to work with, the code needs to differentiate between which tomcat should be run depending on the site to be tested...

The output when the code has run is as follows:

```
manchester
In convert method
In process method 
Council: claims_manchestertest is running successfully..
```

Each of the methods get executed, telling me the code is being hit but not run correctly...

I then check my terminal to see if the tomcat server has been initialised by using:

ps -ax tomcat

However, there is no tomcat instance running!?

Please help! If you need more information, please ask me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you have to use tomcat embedded

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

https://dzone.com/articles/embedded-tomcat-minimal

http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-run-embedded-tomcat-with-maven/

Hope you find some good info here

Johan

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but its not really what im after (I dont think). The application is not a web app and many of the examples you gave are using web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found a solution... Running a shell script seems to work for me. Just simply by passing the path to the ProcessBuilder of the shell script and a parameter. The tomcat server will then successfully start. Heres my solution:

```
    String runShellScriptPath = "/Users/joshuadunn/workspace/update/startTomcat.sh";



private void runCouncilProcess(String councilName) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder buildProcess = new ProcessBuilder(runShellScriptPath, councilName);

 **** Specifically the line above - Takes the string path and the council name for the correct tomcat to be started ****

        buildProcess.start();

        System.out.println("Council: " + councilName + " is running successfully..");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```